# How to make emacs execute function only a specific dir/file doesn't exist

Tags: emacs

I want Emacs to execute a function if and only if a specific directory or file under `.emacs.d` doesn't exist. What should I add to `init.el`?

Suppose that the dir or file name is `dir`, and the function name is `fun`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a beginner `Lisp` programmer but probably something like this:

```
(setq dir "~/.emacs.d")

(defun fun()
  (message "fun called")
  )

(defun funp(dir fn)
  (if (not (file-exists-p dir)) (funcall fn))
  )
```

Set `dir` to what you need. Usage:

```
(funp dir 'fun)
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use **file-directory-p** - _Return t if FILENAME names an existing directory_

Comment: I think the fact that the question names the "dir/file" as `dir` caused confusion :)

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguous of `dir/file`... it does means `dir` or `file`, I will edit my post to correct it.

Comment: I have some code I've used for a long time to do something similar - when I try to open a file in a non-existent directory it prompts to create the directory. This question led me to that function - which uses **file-directory-p**...